# What software can write to Cache memory?

Tags: memory, performance, cpu-cache, computer-science

I was working through a Higher Computing past paper and the following question came up

> Describe a situation where the cache memory would not improve the
>   processor’s performance (1 mark)

The answer (that I personally think is extreamly weak) given in the marking scheme is

> Where the instruction is not in cache and main memory
>   must be accessed

When thinking about other answers I thought that if a program made inneficint use of processer cache it could slow down, like a memory leak in RAM. Then I realised that I dont know if programs are able to control what is writen to or from cache memory, a little research didn't help. What I would like to know is at what level is cache memory handeld, software programs, operating system or by the processer itself? And wopuld there indeed be any situation in which cache memory would not improve or even be detrimental to the computer's performance?

Cheers, kerr_max

Comment: First off, what kind of cache are we talking about? Most caches the CPU knows are not directly accessible by software (in fact I can't think of any).  The CPU and other components are responsible for managing cache. As for usefulness, a cache of data is only useful if the data is used more than once, so for instance, an algorithm that loads and processes lots of memory once, will keep flushing and refilling the cache, but the cache itself never gets read, just overwritten all over again.

Comment: To clarify, it is the cache found on the CPU itself, and thanks for your answer, it kind of answers my question.